# nginx serve page depending on protocol

Tags: http, nginx, http2

I want to simultaneously optimize my site for HTTP/2 and HTTP/1.x. For HTTP/2 (and SPDY), since there are no additional round-trips for requests, I'd like to serve my CSS and JS files separately, to gain the benefit of independently caching each file. However, if I only did that, HTTP/1.x clients would suffer from additional round-trips; so for them, I'd like to serve my CSS and JS files concatenated.

Ideally, HTTP/2 users would be served this HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet-1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet-2.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script-1.js"></script>
    <script src="script-2.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And HTTP/1.x users would be served this HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="all-stylesheets.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="all-scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to configure nginx to serve different HTML files depending on the client's protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do so via the [`$server_protocol`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_server_protocol) variable. I would usually recommend to interpolate file locations by variable expansion. But in this case I fear this would leave you open to injection attacks as the content of this variable seems to be copied verbatim from the request line.

There is a solution by exploiting the [ngx_http_map_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html), though. Assuming your site sits in `/srv/www`:

```
map $server_protocol $version {
    default       "1.1";
    "HTTP/2.0"    "2.0";
    # extra case for any SPDY version
    "~SPDY/"      "2.0";
}

server {
    listen            [::]:80;
    # The line below requires a working SSL configuration!
    listen            [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name       example.com
    root              /srv/www/http-1.1/htdocs;

    location / {
        root          /srv/www/http-$version/htdocs;
        try_files     $uri $uri/ @fallback;
    }

    # fallback for HTTP/1.1 files. If this fails as well, we get a 404.
    location @fallback {
        try_files     $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

This would serve all requests out of `/srv/www/http-2.0/htdocs` for HTTP/2.0 requests and out of `/srv/www/http-1.1/htdocs` for all others. If a resource specially crafted for HTTP/2.0 cannot be found, the coresponding file for HTTP/1.1 is being served as a fallback.

Comment: @Jackson: Good question. I think no, SPDY will probably introduce itself as e.g. `SPDY/3.1`. The map would have to include a case for when `SPDY/` is a prefix of the protocol identifier. I'll update my answer in a bit.

Comment: @Jackson: I've updated my answer to allow for a fallback. This is essentially a deduplication measure so you only need to pay attention to the resources specifically designated for HTTP/2. Also: nicer directory names.

Comment: At first I got the error `"map" directive is not allowed here`, but moving `map` out of the `server {}` block fixed it. Worked after that!

Comment: @Jackson: Ah, right. I fixed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Are you sure that the port 80 line is correct? Shouldn't that include 443?

Comment: @StephenKing: Nope, that line is fine. An additional `listen` directive for ssl/spdy/http2 is actually in order, though. Corrected, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks. Are you really sure that you can specify both `spdy` _and_ `http2`? IIRC only one is possible. In the [`ngx_http_v2_module` docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v2_module.html), there's also the `$http2` variable mentioned. Wouldn't that help to implement it without the map?

Comment: @StephenKing: Actually no. The http2 module has superseeded the spdy one. It would've made a bit of sense as the protocol identifier differ between these two. And yes, `$http2` could be used to interpolate the document root, but the solution with map offers more control, so I'd always prefer that. It also makes neater pathnames as `h2` and `h2c` are not as self-descriptive.

Comment: @StephenKing for the fun of it, I just tossed `http2 spdy` into a `listen` directive: While spawning an ugly warning, it actually works. The more you know :D